# Different implementation for different parameters

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to write different method implementations for different parameters? Something like this:

```
class Foo
    def some_method("lorem")
        true
    end
    def some_method("ipsum")
        false
    end
end

a = Foo.new
a.some_method("lorem")
=> true
a.some_method("ipsum")
=> false
```

Something similar to Haskell pattern matching

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very easy. Ruby supports 2-way conditionals, written `if`/`then`/`else` and multi-way conditionals, written `case`/`when`/`then`/`else`:

```
class Foo
  def some_method(word)
    case word
    when 'lorem' then true
    when 'ipsem' then false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a `Hash` map, if you want to avoid branching conditionals:

```
class Foo
  WORDS = { "lorem" => true, "ipsem" => false }

  def some_method(word)
    WORDS[word]
  end
end
```

Or in your specific case, some simple predicate logic could do it, but might not be extendable:

```
class Foo
  def some_method(word)
    word == "lorem"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Method overloading is not supported by ruby because it doesnt use data declaration.

I think the closest thing you can do is to use a switch to check the data type and do something different in every block.

Example

```
 case item.class
   when MyClass
     # do something here
   when Array
     # do something different here
   when String
     # do a third thing
   end
```

But writting different implementations using the same number of parameters cant be achieved.

Comment: This won't work. `item.class` is always going to be a `Class`, never an `Array` or a `String` or a `MyClass`, so none of your cases will ever match. Also, the OP wants to differentiate on value.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, what I meaned was that he could do "something like that", but now that I see I didnt say that in the post, well, sorry, my bad, ill be more careful next time.